# Airflow app init by python script as one point

Tags: airflow

I create python script for common initialization of app based on airflow:

- common: web admin user, db migration
- app entities: connections, pools etc. it based on app code entities (no global import )

And i use cli tools directly, code example:

```py
import logging
import os
import sys
from argparse import Namespace
from dataclasses import MISSING, dataclass, field
from functools import partial

from airflow.cli.commands.user_command import users_create
from airflow.settings import Session

from common.connections import init_connections


LOG_HEAD = "[app][init]"
MISSING_TYPE = type(MISSING)
GET_ENV = os.environ.get


# ============================
# Auxiliary tools
# ============================
class AppInitException(BaseException):
    pass


def _check_env_set(log_head, dc):
    """Check dataclass on env load."""
    skipped_env = []

    for arg, value in dc.__dict__.items():
        field_ = dc.__dataclass_fields__[arg]
        default_factory = field_.default_factory

        if value is None and default_factory and isinstance(field_.default, MISSING_TYPE):
            skipped_env.append(default_factory.args[0])

    if skipped_env:
        raise AppInitException(f"{log_head} Env variables must be set: {', '.join(skipped_env)}.")


# ============================
# Config env based entities
# ============================

@dataclass
class AdminUser:
    # WEB user
    username: str = field(default_factory=partial(GET_ENV, "_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME", None))
    password: str = field(default_factory=partial(GET_ENV, "_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD", None))
    firstname: str = "APP"  # _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_FIRSTNAME
    lastname: str = "Heh"  # _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_LASTNAME
    email: str = ""  # _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_EMAIL
    role: str = "Admin"  # _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_ROLE
    use_random_password: bool = False


# ============================
# Init app tools
# ============================

def create_admin_user():
    """Create WEB-user"""
    log_head = f"{LOG_HEAD}[user]"
    logging.info(f"{log_head} Create user if does not exist.")

    # Load settings
    user = AdminUser()
    _check_env_set(log_head, user)

    # Apply
    users_create(Namespace(**user.__dict__))
    logging.info(f"{log_head} Success.")


def main():
    logging.info(f"{LOG_HEAD} Start init app Airflow based.")

    # Common initialization
    # db_migrate()
    create_admin_user()

    # Additional
    session = Session()

    init_connections(LOG_HEAD, session)

    logging.info(f"{LOG_HEAD} End.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except AppInitException as ex:
        logging.error(ex)
        sys.exit(1)
```

Goal
One point app initialization, future flexible deployment.
Questions:
It is bad idea?